# Elassandra - Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress

Tags: java, cassandra, elassandra, cassandra-stress

I'm trying to run an `cassandra-stress` on a elassandra cluster.

Buy I'm always getting this error:

> $pwd

`/usr/share/cassandra/tools/bin`

> $./cassandra-stress

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress`

E edited the cassandra-stress file, and I checked that 
the file has this content:

```
"$JAVA" -server -ea -cp "$CLASSPATH" $JVM_OPTS \
-Dcassandra.storagedir="$cassandra_storagedir" \
-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback-tools.xml \
org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress $@
```

But does not exists the file `Stress.java` and `Stress.class` on system.

I found it here: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/tools/stress/src/org/apache/cassandra/stress/Stress.java

But I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until v6.2.3.10, stress.jar was not packaged with the elassandra distribution.
This has been fixed in v6.2.3.11.

As a workaround one can use the stresstool from the official Cassandra distribution.